# Sort groups of rows where field values are the same in certain columns

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, awk, python, sort

I have a text file like this:

```
1 bob A
1 jim B
1 Kate A
1 Nancy C
1 bill A
1 Jason A
2 James B
2 fill B
2 cake C
2 lucky C
2 Lucy A
2 lily B
```

How can I order the data by column 3 within each 1 & 2 group?
The output should be:

```
1 bob A
1 Kate A
1 bill A
1 Jason A
1 jim B
1 Nancy C
2 Lucy A
2 James B
2 fill B
2 lily B
2 cake C
2 lucky C
```

Note that `Kate` appears before `bill` in the output
because they are in that order in the input.

The values of column 1 are large, it goes from 1, 2, to 2000, so I was thinking about awk print while comparing row numbers and not just equal to a certain value.

Comment: (1) Are you saying (as your example seems to suggest) that all the lines (i.e., rows or records) with `$1` = `1` are together (consecutive) in the input file, and then all the lines with `$1` = `2` are together, and then all the lines with `$1` = `3` are together, … and then all the lines with `$1` = `42` are together, … and finally all the lines with `$1` = ``2000`` are together?  And you want the output to have the same property?   (2) Please confirm what I wrote about the `$2` values.

Answer (score 6):

`sort` the file numerically by first column, lexicographically by third column:

```
sort -s -k1n,1 -k3,3 file
```

Note: `-s` is an extension to the POSIX specification

Comment: Note that the question says that `$1` ranges up to 2000, so the file might have 12000 lines. `sort` will read this *entire* file and then sort it. This will take at least *n log(n)* time; i.e., 12000×log(12000). This probably consumes more resources than sorting 2000 groups of six lines.

Comment: @G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica' 12000 lines is still not very many though.

Comment: You should mention that this requires GNU sort for `-s`.

Answer (score 2):

If you have GNU sort for `-s` then see [@guest's solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/586746/133219), otherwise using any cat+sort+cut:

```
$ cat -n file | sort -k2,2n -k4,4 -k1,1n | cut -f2-
1 bob A
1 Kate A
1 bill A
1 Jason A
1 jim B
1 Nancy C
2 Lucy A
2 James B
2 fill B
2 lily B
2 cake C
2 lucky C
```

Answer (score 1):

Collect each line in an array. When the first word of a line is not the same as the previous first word, print the array sorted by the third word. This may be somewhat over the top when a simple `sort` can do the job. The below does not account for input files that differ from the format shown in the question.

gawk:

```
BEGIN {ors=ORS; ORS=""; PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_str_asc"}

$1!=r {
    output()
    delete a
    r=$1
}
{
    a[$3]=a[$3] $0 ors
}

END {
    output()
}

function output() {
    for (i in a)
        print a[i]
}
```

---

python:

```py
import fileinput, operator
r=''; a=[]
def out():
    for p in sorted(a,key=operator.itemgetter(2)):
        print(' '.join(p))

for line in fileinput.input():
    x = line.rstrip().split()
    if r!=x[0]:
        r=x[0]
        if a:
            out()
            del a[:]
    a.append(x)
out()
```

---

perl:

```
perl -lae 'sub out {foreach(sort keys %a) {print $a{$_}}} BEGIN {$ors=$\;$\=""}
    if ($F[0] ne $r) {$r=$F[0]; out; %a=()}
    $a{$F[2]}=$a{$F[2]}.$_.$ors; END{out}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here’s the `awk` solution you wanted. 
(Well, `gawk` [GNU `awk`], to be specific; this won’t work in POSIX `awk`.)

```
awk '
        function dump() {
                PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_str_asc"
                for (arg3 in group) {
                        PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_num_asc"
                        for (line_num in group[arg3]) {
                                print group[arg3][line_num]
                        }
                        PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_str_asc"
                }
        }
        {
                if ($1 != saved_arg1) {
                        dump()
                        delete group
                        saved_arg1 = $1
                }
                group[$3][NR] = $0
        }
        END {
                dump()
        }
    '
```

The main work begins in the middle. 
For each line, if its `$1` value is different
from the most recent one we’ve seen,
that means that we’re entering a new group. 
Dump the data from the previous group (i.e., write it to the output),
delete the saved data for the previous group,
and then remember the new `$1` value.

Then, in either case, add the current line to the `group` array. 
This is a two-dimensional array, indexed by `$3` value and `NR`
(line number). 
So, for example, for the first six lines of your sample input, we get

```
group["A"][1] = "1 bob A"
group["B"][2] = "1 jim B"
group["A"][3] = "1 Kate A"
group["C"][4] = "1 Nancy C"
group["A"][5] = "1 bill A"
group["A"][6] = "1 Jason A"
```

When we see `$1` = `2` on line 7,
we call the `dump` function (defined at the top of the program). 
`for (arg3 in group)` sets `arg3` to `A`, `B` and `C`, in that order. 
Then, for `arg3` = `A`, the loop `for (line_num in group[arg3])`
(i.e., `for (line_num in group["A"])` sets `line_num`
to `1`, `3`, `5` and `6`, in that order. 
And so we print out

```
1 bob A
1 Kate A
1 bill A
1 Jason A
```

And so on for the other `$3` values. 
And so on for the other `$1` values.